How to purge unused css with NextJS and SCSS
I have the following directory structure for the NextJS app.
Project directory structure screenshot
Now I want my pages to load with only the required css and not with unnecessary css. I tried to setup the PurgeCSS from link https://purgecss.com/guides/next.html and my postcss.config.js looks like follows:
module.exports = {
"plugins": [
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes",
    [
        "postcss-preset-env",
        {
            "autoprefixer": {
                "flexbox": "no-2009"
            },
            "stage": 3,
            "features": {
                "custom-properties": false
            }
        }
    ],
    [
        '@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss',
        {
            content: [
                './src/components/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
                './src/common/**/*.{ts,tsx}'
            ],
            defaultExtractor: content => content.match(/[\w-/:]+(?<!:)/g) || [],
            safelist: ["html", "body"]
        }
    ],
]

}
next.config.js is configured as:
const withCss = require("@zeit/next-css");
const withPurgeCss = require("next-purgecss");

module.exports = withCss(withPurgeCss());

Project is building without any error, but not sure how to check if it is really works and my doubt is that I have module.scss files so will it work with it because the link I referred is giving example of css instead of scss?
I tried to ask the question regarding the NextJS and Css for optimization.
